# Payment Invoice tracking over calendar year

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

Ok, so I am trying to create an Excel sheet that will be used to track payment schedules on a monthly basis. However, I am finding it difficult to find a formula that would work. My issue is that if a new customer started with us in the month 06/02/2019 example Column 4.

I have started the monthly calendar from November 2018 to December 2019. Once they start the contract I want the cells in November to January to state Not required in the "Amount Due". Also If they get months free for example 2 months it needs to state Free on the next occurring months.

[Excel Monthly Payment Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1j09v7w62hmjqar/MonthlyPayments.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: That's a busy sheet: inputs (i.e. customer details in A:I); calculations and the output (i.e. Paid = Yes or Paid + No for each month) all on one sheet.  Have you considered separating the elements into tables or sheets?

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald I have not thought of that yet, Would you suggest vLook up then? Do you know of any examples online that has already got this? Kind regards,